# Typescript error: Type '{ onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm having a hard time trying to understand why my code isn't working.

I'm trying to build a carousel image gallery using react and typescript and i'm having problems when I try to use "onClick" on the left and right arrows for navigation.

I get the following errors:

> Type `'{ onClick: () => void; }'` is not assignable to type `'IntrinsicAttributes'`.
> Property `'onClick'` does not exist on type `'IntrinsicAttributes'`.

Here's my code:

```
const Carousel = ({ slides }) => {
   
    return (
        <section className="slider">

            <ArrowRight onClick = {nextSlide} /> //The error is here!
            <ArrowLeft onClick = { () => prevSlide() } /> //and here!

            {slides.map((slide, index) => {
                return (
                    <div className="img-slide">
                        <img src={slide.image} />
                        <div className="rolo-slide">
                            {/* <img src={slide.image} onClick={slides.setCurrent(index)} /> */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </section>
    )
}
export default Carousel
```

Here's what ArrowLeft and Right are, they're just a span, I made the arrows using CSS.

```
function ArrowLeft() {
    return (
        <span className="arrow left"></span>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is type `IntrinsicAttributes`?

Comment: Please show us the definitions of `ArrowRight` and `ArrowLeft`. Ideally, reduce the problem to a [mcve] and post just that code, without extraneous other parts, to the question (and preferably also a link to that same code in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)). That makes it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: `ArrowRight` component doesn't have `onClick` in its props typing definition.

Comment: @zerkms that's the type that represents the properties shared by all jsx elements. Ie, it looks like they havn't given a type to ArrowRight or ArrowLeft, and so it's saying "not all elements have an onClick"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Oh, I'm sorry, I'll make sure to keep that in mind next time! I just updated the code with the ArrowRight and Left. They're just a span, I made them with CSS because I had a hard time trying to import Font Awesome, because I'm using Gatsby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ArrowLeft` doesn't accept any props at all, so TypeScript won't let you assign an `onClick` prop to it that it doesn't accept.

Update `ArrowLeft` so it accepts an `onClick` handler. For functional components I usually use function expressions rather than declarations:

```typescript
const ArrowLeft: React.FC<{onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>}> = ({onClick}) => {
    return (
        <span className="arrow left" onClick={onClick}></span>
    );
};
```

Some notes on that:

- `React.FC` is an alias for `React.FunctionComponent`. It tells TypeScript that `ArrowLeft` is a function component.
- `React.FC` has an optional type parameter to specify the type of the props that the functional component expects (they'll be combined with the usual props). The `<>` after `React.FC` provides a *type argument* describing the props object this functional component accepts.
- `onClick?:` says the `onClick` prop is optional.
- `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>` says that the type of the prop (if it's given) is a mouse event handler for an HTML element.
- Notice how I've forwarded the `onClick` handler on to the `span` so that it does get called when the `span` is clicked.

I've used an arrow function because they're (slightly) lighter-weight than traditional functions, but you can use a traditional function if you prefer:

```typescript
const ArrowLeft: React.FC<{onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>}> = function({onClick}) {
    return (
        <span className="arrow left" onClick={onClick}></span>
    );
};
```

---

BTW: Don't worry about memorizing all of these types. You'll want to know `React.FC` of course (or `React.Component` for `class` components), but for instance for the `onClick` above you don't have to magically know it. In any decent IDE, you could start out with that not there and do this:

```
// To start with
const ArrowLeft: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <span className="arrow left" onClick={}></span>
    );
};
```

...then hover your mouse over the `onClick` part in the `span`. My IDE (VS Code) tells me that the type of `onClick` is `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLSpanElement> | undefined`:

[image: VS Code IDE showing tooltip for span's onClick]

The `| undefined` part I handled in the props by using `?` to make it optional, and I changed `HTMLSpanElement` to just the more general `HTMLElement` because there wasn't any need for the code using `ArrowLeft` to know that it uses a `span`, specifically, vs. a `div` or `i` or whatever.